# sprintf confusion (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, printf, dicom

Quick question,

I would like to make a count from 50-70 using sprintf in Matlab. This example prints 0101-0120

```
for i = 1:20
    filename = sprintf('Brain_01%02d.dcm', i);
    [X(:,:,1,i), amap] = dicomread(filename);
end
```

How would I change this to print 0151-0170?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seemed obvious at first, but it seems like another issue might be related to the indexing of `X` getting broken if `i` doesn't start at one.  Here's one way to address that while handling pre-allocation of `X`,

```
imgInds = 151:170;
di = dicominfo(sprintf('Brain_%04d.dcm',imgInds(1)));
X = zeros(di.Height,di.Width,1,numel(imgInds),class(dicomread(di))); % modify

for i = 1:numel(imgInds),
    filename = sprintf('Brain_%04d.dcm', imgInds(i));
    [X(:,:,1,i), amap] = dicomread(filename);
end
```

For clarity, I think it is better to build your `sprintf` with `%04d` instead of `01%02d`.  You should set the size of `X` accordingly on the line labeled `modify`, particularly the third dimension since I assume your actual code will not have this be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this should do it:

```
for i = 51:70
    filename = sprintf('Brain_01%02d.dcm', i);
    [X(:,:,1,i), amap] = dicomread(filename);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your responses! Actually all I needed to do (for my purposes) was:

```
for i = 1:20
filename = sprintf('Brain_01%02d.dcm', i + 49);
[X(:,:,1,i), amap] = dicomread(filename);
end
```

which made the count start from 50.